# Is it possible to publish a blog post on behalf of another user in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, blog, on-behalf

If you're the one publishing a blog post, but you're doing it on behalf of another user, is there a way to show that?

Answer (score 1):

Each blog post is essentially a list entry with a giant free text field for the main content area. You can open the list settings and customise the metadata columns so that part of the displayed metadata is a manually selectable person field and give it the Custom Column name 'Author' or something similar. Then when you publish a new post you can specify the user you want credited with it's authorship.